# Issues with Nestable JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jQuery nested list module:

https://github.com/dbushell/Nestable

This is an old version and no longer supported.  There are similar packages, but this one is easy to use and is clean.

The demo works:

Demo: http://dbushell.github.io/Nestable/

I started with pasting the demo code into my Rails app it works as intended except one huge issue which I will have trouble explaining other than a video:

[image: Imgur]

The list items won't indent until you slightly drag them up onto a parent slightly.  In the demo these just know to indent after a certain y mouse movement.

I created a Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/jasper502/oLyfc8m0/8/

It works fine in the the fiddle also.  I can't easily post my code - it's production.  I suspect that it's the outer nested divs etc that I have in my code.  I a standard top nav bar / side nav bar / content layout.  The crazy thing is the template I used for this site has this as a demo and it works fine also:

http://webapplayers.com/inspinia_admin-v2.9.2/nestable_list.html

I have seen issues like this where element position etc are all thrown off by this.  I had issues with tooltips etc. and it was solved with something like this:

```
$('body').nestable({
  selector: '.dd'
});
```

vs

```
$('.dd').nestable({ /* config options */ });
```

Unfortunately my JS / jQuery / CSS skills are limited and not sure where to start hunting this down.  I am going to start playing with that Fiddle until I break it to reproduce the issue - just hoping someone can suggest a fix or where to start looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I missed the fact that in my code I was building the list in a `fields_for` loop in a form.  Extra hidden inputs are inserted BETWEEN the list items.  This caused the bug.

```
<div class="dd" id="nestable">   <ol class="dd-list">
    <li class="dd-item" data-id="1">
      <div class="dd-handle">1 - Lorem ipsum</div>
    </li>

    <input type="hidden" value="4" name="items_attributes[0][id]" id="items_attributes_0_id">

    <li class="dd-item" data-id="2"><button data-action="collapse" type="button">Collapse</button><button data-action="expand" type="button" style="display: none;">Expand</button>
      <div class="dd-handle">2 - Dolor sit</div>
      <ol class="dd-list">
        <li class="dd-item" data-id="3">
          <div class="dd-handle">3 - Adipiscing elit</div>
        </li>
        <li class="dd-item" data-id="4">
          <div class="dd-handle">4 - Nonummy nibh</div>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li class="dd-item" data-id="5"><button data-action="collapse" type="button">Collapse</button><button data-action="expand" type="button" style="display: none;">Expand</button>
      <div class="dd-handle">5 - Consectetuer</div>
      <ol class="dd-list">
        <li class="dd-item" data-id="6">
          <div class="dd-handle">6 - Aliquam erat</div>
        </li>
        <li class="dd-item" data-id="7">
          <div class="dd-handle">7 - Veniam quis</div>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li class="dd-item" data-id="8">
      <div class="dd-handle">8 - Tation ullamcorper</div>
    </li>
    <li class="dd-item" data-id="9">
      <div class="dd-handle">9 - Ea commodo</div>
    </li>   </ol> </div>
```

If the form inputs are inside the 'dd-handle' div all is fine.